# Python subprocess communicate, top shows low cpu usage

Tags: python, subprocess, cpu, popen

Given a very simple script like:

```
import subprocess

while True:
    x = subprocess.Popen('ls -ltr /usr/lib', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

I get the following "top" cpu usage on my laptop's Ubuntu 12.04 (32bit), celeron 2-core:

```
x = subprocess.Popen('ls -l /usr/lib', ... 
python3.2.3: 6%, python2.7.3: 5% (ls 0%)

x = subprocess.Popen('gcc --version', ...
python3.2.3: 22%, python2.7.3: 18% (gcc 0%)

x = subprocess.Popen('pwd', ...
python3.2.3: 47%, python 2.7.3: 35% (pwd 0%)
```

If subprocess.Popen is replaced by os.popen, the results are different:

```
x = os.popen('ls /usr/lib').read()
python3.2.3: 8%, python2.7.3: 3% (gcc 0%)

x = os.popen('gcc --version').read()
python3.2.3: 45%, python 2.7.3: 9%

x = os.popen('pwd').read()
python3.2.3: 68%, python 2.7.3: 22%
```

Why is cpu usage so low and so different? I tried this on core i5 and atom ubuntus, and the results were close to 100% (3.2) and 80%(2.7). Nothing else in top, what's wrong with my platform?

Comment: What's exactly wrong or unexpected in your results?

Comment: As I've mentioned I tried this on core i5 and atom ubuntus, and the results were close to 100% (3.2) and 80%(2.7). I expect 100% CPU load on any platform.

Comment: This is a terrible way of loading a CPU -- you're generating a huge number of really cheap tasks, instead of one difficult one. Tell it to factor a large number or something.

Comment: If I'd really needed to read one constant string infinitely many times I would definitely organized the architecture of my project some other way, but that's just the simple approximation of my problem.

Comment: `.communicate()` tries to do I/O.

Answer (score 1):

At least some of the problem will be that you're using the disk rather than the CPU with some of these commands. "ls -l /usr/lib" will definitely involve disk access (as it runs stat() on each file): I could believe that loading gcc involves less disk access, and the shell builtin pwd even less.

I could also believe that maybe os.popen, subprocess.Popen and the Python3 versions have differences in whether they spawn a new shell, what attributes that shell has (and thus e.g. whether it has to read /etc/profile from disk), and so on.

As the comments already say, computationally-intensive work will get you higher CPU usage than IO-bound work like "ls -l". The following brings me to 100% CPU quite nicely:

```
while True:
    a = 11*11
```

Comment: subprocess.Popen('echo "hello"' -- just 35% :(

Comment: You may still be doing some IO work to spawn a new shell. What does 'iostat -xc 1' report?

Comment: (Also, echoing to the screen is still not really computational work, though I don't know how TTY IO works.)

Comment: #!/bin/bash
while :
do
echo "hello"
done

shell script gives me 100%

Comment: That's pretty conclusive, then - popen must be doing some work (e.g. loading the 'bash' binary) which uses the disk rather than pure CPU.

Comment: thank you very much for iostat, it seems that i really missed top's "ltm" keys and the original question's base is totally wrong. iostat shows 60%! anyway i don't get 100% i must rethink the problem and close the question for the moment